# Convert tailwind and external CSS into inline styles

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am using tailwind classes along with custom classes defined in external stylesheet. I need to convert my code to inline styling for using somewhere else. How can I do this?

HTML:

```html
<div class="lg:w-1/4 w-full h-auto px-4 py-2 bg-orange border-2 shadow-lg border-orange rounded-2xl flex gap-2 items-center">
    <img src="/Icons/illustration_no-payment.svg" alt="illustration_no-payment">
    <div class="h-auto flex flex-col justify-between">
        <h3 class="text-mont text-sm text-lblack font-bold">Oh no, your Payment Failed!</h3>
        <p class="text-mont text-xs text-l2black">Please contact us directly so we can put this right without delay. We appreciate your patience.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.text-lblack {
    color: #1d1d1d;
}
.border-orange {
    border-color: #fd4949;
}
.text-l2black {
    color: #444445;
}
```